# I was never asked to create a password for my Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: wallet

Last week I downloaded a Bitcoin Wallet from bitcoin.com.  It is on my iPad.  I also put the same wallet on my iPhone.  As I was setting the wallet up, I recorded my 12-words, placed them in the proper order when asked, I wrote them down, then sent my wallet info to iCloud using the provided address and created a password for that.  It is a file in iCloud named "wallet.data"... but... is that the only password I need?  My iCloud password??  I don't recall being asked to create any other password than that.  Please help.  My Wallet now has 1000's in funds received but will I ever be able to spend it??  I'm a bit in a panic at the moment.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

As a general rule do not store your seed phrase on services like iCloud or Google Drive etc. If your account is compromised by someone with malintent, your crypto will likely disappear forever.

You don't need a password and even if the app required you to make a password to login you wouldn't really need the password to access your coins. You only need your seed phrase.

You can input your seed phrase with the same bitcoin wallet program or almost any other
and gain access to your coins again. As long as you have the seed phrase, your good.

Also, I would move those coins to a new address with a new seed phrase if you value those funds.

One more thing, hardware wallets are generally your most secure option.

Comment: I have the seed phrase, yes... I was befuddled when I tried to export my wallet to a desktop version from the same place (bitcoin.com).  I typed in the words leaving a space between each, but it wasn't accepted.  Do I need to enter the words in a certain way?  (Thanks for your earlier reply)

Comment: Did you try more than once? Maybe you had a spelling error or the order was incorrect? Did you possibly copy the phrase down incorrectly?

Comment: I did try exporting my wallet more than once.  Didn't work at all.  I'm probably forgetting to do something basic.  I'll experiment.  Also, I'm borderline "OCD" when it comes to filling in text/data.  Double- and triple-checking everything... that's me... so I'm sure I got it right.  About the password that I was so worried about... I successfully opened the "wallet.data" file using the password and a downloadable decryption tool from bitcoin.com.  I think I'll burn the "wallet.data" file to a DVD and remove it from iCloud.  Do you think that's a good idea?  Thx again for your help. 

Comment: If the amount is quite large I would just create a whole new wallet.But if it was encrypted maybe its fine. I never took that route to be honest. It doesn't hurt to play things safe, generally speaking. 

You tried exporting or importing several times?

Comment: I tried exporting from the original wallet on my iPad to a new wallet on my desktop computer so that I would have access to the same account in both places.  It worked between my iPad and iPhone but that was just a case of scanning a QR code.  My mac desktop is old and can't do QR Codes.